# stop an element from expanding its width when it hits another element’s fixed width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that expands as the user types into a textarea that copies its text into the div. I want that div to stop expanding its width when it hits the outer edge of the other div that is its grandparent, but I have found no solutions online for how to do that. Currently when the div hits the outer edge it just moves itself to the next line below until it is the only element on the line (which I do not want). I'd like it to expand its height downwards.

[See this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/26885/) for exactly what I mean and type into the first textarea

I also don't want to hardcode any pixel values (like `max-width: 16px;` or whatever). I'd like to make this dynamic enough that it works no matter how much space the div has available to expand to.

```js
 function copyText(callingName, receivingName){
      var significantDiv = $('[name=' + callingName +']');
      var significantSpan = $("#" + receivingName);
      significantSpan.text(significantDiv.val());
    }//end copyText()
```

```css
body{
 background-color: rgb(90, 90, 96);
 font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode";
  font-weight:bold; 
  font-size:30px
}

input[type=text]{
 border-radius:30px;
 background-color:rgb(128, 128, 137);
 border-style:none;
 padding:15px;
 outline:none;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

input[type=text]:focus{
 background-color:rgb(149, 149, 160);
}

div.addP{
 float:left;
 min-width:50%;
 max-width:50%;
}

.textAreaColumn{
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 outline: solid 1px lime;
}

#someText0Span{
 display: inline-block;

 outline: solid 1px orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="addP" style= "outline:solid 1px blue;">space</div>
  <div class="addP" style="outline:solid 1px red"><!--Everything in this div is in the right column of info.-->
    <div class="inputRow">
      Type some text:
      <div class="textAreaColumn" id="someTextColumn">
        <div class="singleTextAreaContainer">
          <input type="text" name="someText0" onkeyup="copyText('someText0','someText0Span')">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inputRow">
      Some text:
      <div class="textAreaColumn" id="moreTextColumn">
        <div class="singleTextAreaContainer">
          <input type="text" name="moreText0"> <div id="someText0Span"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please add code in SO not in jsfiddle.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**. THERE WAS A BIG RED NOTICE TO THIS EFFECT...DID YOU MISS IT?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a bit difficult for me to follow because of how you've used selectors, so I have started off on a blank slate but you should be able to use what I have done below in your own code

```js
function copyText(callingName, receivingName){
      var significantDiv = $('[name=' + callingName +']');
      var significantSpan = $("#" + receivingName);
      significantSpan.text(significantDiv.val());
    }
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px
}

input {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: 2px solid;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
 }

[name] {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  
 }

.container {
  width: 300px;
  border: 3px solid;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}


/*Code that you should pay attention to is below*/

input {
  float: left;
  
}

span {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto; /*turn element to block formatting context*/
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name='input' 

onkeyup="copyText('input','output')">

<div class="container">
  <input type="text">
  <span id='output'></span>
</div>
```

The way this works is that I float the input to left taking it out of normal flow and turn the output span into a block. Normally block elements below elements that are floated before them will ignore the floated element, come up on the same line as them and slide underneath them.

However, with span I have added a property of:

```
overflow: auto;
```

This turns it into a [block formatting context](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/12/understanding-css-layout-block-formatting-context/) and one of the features of these kinds of elements is that they respect the width of floated elements next to them and will sit next to them taking up 100% of the width left next to float, growing and shrinking dynamically with the size of the floated.

Lastly, I added:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

to the `span` so that longs words break across multiple lines.

*Be aware with floating elements the parent element's height will collapse if there are no other elements larger than the floated element in the container. You can get around this using a clearfix solution*

Answer (score 0):

```js
function copyText(callingName, receivingName){
      var significantDiv = $('[name=' + callingName +']');
      var significantSpan = $("#" + receivingName);
      significantSpan.text(significantDiv.val());
    }//end copyText()
```

```css
body{
 background-color: rgb(90, 90, 96);
 font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode";
  font-weight:bold; 
  font-size:30px
}

input[type=text]{
 border-radius:30px;
 background-color:rgb(128, 128, 137);
 border-style:none;
 padding:15px;
 outline:none;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

input[type=text]:focus{
 background-color:rgb(149, 149, 160);
}

div.addP{
 float:left;
 min-width:50%;
 max-width:50%;
}

.textAreaColumn{
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 outline: solid 1px lime;
}

#someText0Span{
 display: inline-block;

 outline: solid 1px orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="addP" style= "outline:solid 1px blue;">space</div>
  <div class="addP" style="outline:solid 1px red"><!--Everything in this div is in the right column of info.-->
    <div class="inputRow">
      Type some text:
      <div class="textAreaColumn" id="someTextColumn">
        <div class="singleTextAreaContainer">
          <input type="text" name="someText0" onkeyup="copyText('someText0','someText0Span')">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inputRow">
      Some text:
      <div class="textAreaColumn" id="moreTextColumn">
        <div class="singleTextAreaContainer" >
          <input type="text" name="moreText0"> <div id="someText0Span" style="display=table;overflow:scrolling;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```